# What exactly defines a WAN?

Tags: router, network, networking, lan, wan

I've found this question but it doesn't seem to answer my question.
[What is the "technical" definition of LAN and WAN](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/what-is-the-technical-definition-of-lan-and-wan)

I know that a Wan consists of more LAN's  together and MAN's and it's covers over a large geographical area. The whole internet is a WAN.

But

1. do WAN's need to consists more than one LAN in order to be called as WAN ?If so, the geographical area covers is so small. Then how it's called a WAN. If not, what's the name of the network?
2. If WAN's  cover a large geographical area, then if two computers are connected over a distance of 1 lakh km over a fibre-optic cable as point to point connection theoritically, then will that be called as WAN?
3. Can there be WAN without them consisting of LAN?
4. What's the role of MAN then? and how it differs from WAN ?
5. How companies implement WAN if WAN is covers a large geographical area?

Comment: See the second answer in the linked question. There is no technical definition.

Comment: BTW note that "lakh" is a term local to the indian subcontinent, don't expect people outside that region to know what it means.

Comment: But lakh is also used in youtube to denote views as 1L. So I think most people knows

Comment: I think you are probably seeing a localized version of the youtube interface. I can assure you it doesn't use lakh when viewed from the UK.

Comment: Maybe YouTube's algorithm works by country too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original meanings of *LAN* and *WAN* have long since blurred - rigid technical distinctions have vanished as (more or less) the same technology can be used throughout.

Today, these terms are collective terms used for concepts, for security zoning for instance. Their exact distinction depends on context.